# Is it true or false that a finite there a finite number of perfect codes?

Tags: coding-theory

I am wondering whether or not there are a finite number of perfect codes (codes that satisfy the Hamming Bound) that exist, and why or why not there are a finite number of perfect codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many [Hamming codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) and they are all perfect.